# How to pass Endpoint parameter to Endpoint defined as bean in Spring context

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have camel Fileendpoint defined in following way:

```
<bean id="hotfolderEndpoint" 
          class="org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint"
          factory-bean="camel" 
          factory-method="getEndpoint">       
        <constructor-arg ref="hotfolder" />
</bean>
```

I want to define some File parameters such as preMove, move etc.
Variable hotfolder is String taken from JNDI and I have no impact on it. 
When I define property as

```
<bean id="moveExp" class="org.apache.camel.model.language.SimpleExpression">
 <property name="expression" value="done/${file:name}"/>
</bean>
```

it is not correctly parsed and the file get name done/name

Comment: What is `${file:name}` supposed to be?

Comment: It is supposed to be name of the original file according to thew camel File Language documentation. I have noticed, that even if I use pure uri like file:/inbox?move=/done/${file:name} i get file in done folder named 'name'. It seems as if file language doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I Case

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel">
                <camel:route>
                        <camel:from ref="hotfolderEndpoint"/>
                        <camel:to uri="file://c:/test/myfolder/toEnd"></camel:to>
                </camel:route>
        </camel:camelContext>

        <camel:endpoint id="hotfolderEndpoint" camelContextId="camel"
                uri="file://c:/test/hotfolder?move=backup/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}"/>
```

Result:
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot create directory: c:\test\hotfolder\backup\now:yyyyMMdd\name

II Case DSL

```
from("file://c:/test/myfolder?preMove=inprogress&moveFailed=backup/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}")
                .to("file://c:/test/myfolder/toEnd");
```

Result
preMove works fine (inprogress folder created), but move throws exception:
GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot rename file: GenericFile[c:\test\hotfolder\xxx.txt] to: GenericFile[backup\20100512]

III Case

```
<bean id="hotfolderEndpoint"
         class="org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint"
         factory-bean="camel"
         factory-method="getEndpoint">    
            <constructor-arg ref="hotfolder" />
            <property name="readLock" value="rename" />
            <property name="move" ref="moveExp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="moveExp" class="org.apache.camel.model.language.SimpleExpression">
            <property name="expression" value="done/${file:name.noext}-done.${file:ext}"/>
    </bean>
```

Simlar Problem to Case II

IV Case

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel">
                <camel:route>
                        <camel:from uri="file://c:/test/hotfolder?move=backup/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}"/>
                        <camel:to uri="file://c:/test/myfolder/toEnd"></camel:to>
                </camel:route>
        </camel:camelContext>
```

Result: work as expected

Question: Am I doing sth wrong or there is a bug in Camel

Answer (score 0):

preMove is an option on FileEndpoint so you can just let spring IoC it

```
<bean>
    <property name="preMove" value="done"/>
</bean>
```

And I believe that you can omit ${file:name} if you just want it moved to a folder. Its already documented at the Camel wiki page
http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

BTW: What version of Camel are you using and which OS?

Comment: I'm using Camel 2.2 on Windows XP SP3. Suggested solution wont work because preMove given as String value can not be casted to Expression and thus result in Exception.